# How to handle multipart/form-data with different content-types?

Tags: spring, rest, parsing, web, https

How to parse multipart/form-data using Spring framework which has different content-types?

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------287032381131322
Content-Length: 999   
----------287032381131322
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="targetDevices"
Content-Type: text/JSON
[ “12345678”, “22345678”, “32345678 ]

----------287032381131322
Content-Type:application/octet-stream 
Content-Length:<file length>
<file goes here…>
```

Comment: could you provide your controller structure?

Comment: That's what i was asking, should i use request param by the name? How the variable type will be?

Comment: yes you need to use @RequestParam("controler")  String content and so on, but try adding more detail what you have done so far. e.g. pom file, controller

Comment: I think I'm ok with the pom, my main concern is how do I get the file in the handler? Thanks!

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = MY_URL, method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
public void myMethod(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("targetDevices") MyClass myClass) {
...
}